# I get an InputMismatchException when I enter decimal numbers to variables of the type double

Tags: java

I tried separating them with commas but that didn't solve the problem. The program workes well when I enter integers though. For example, 5.5 50.9 4.5 will make the program crash, but 5 50 4 won't.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    double v0, v1, t;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter v0, v1, and t: ");
    
    v0 = input.nextDouble();
    v1 = input.nextDouble();
    t = input.nextDouble();
            
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your actual input.

Comment: Good you found the solution. Feel free to post it as an actual answer and accept it. Don't put the solution in the question, that's not how stackoverflow works. (See also [ask].) It would still be good to add your inputs to the question, though, so that people can reproduce the issue. When I enter "1.0, 2.0, 3.0" to your new code, it still crashes.

Comment: @Robert thank you for telling me. I did that just now. That's right, I tried using commas instead of spaces and it did crash. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the inputs with spaces, e.g. enter

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
```

This is documented in [Scanner's Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

[Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) usually means spaces, tabs, and line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just needed to use Scanner.useLocale(Locale locale) method though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The new code looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Lab3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double v0, v1, t;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

    System.out.println("Enter v0, v1, and t: ");
    
    v0 = input.nextDouble();
    v1 = input.nextDouble();
    t = input.nextDouble();

    }

}
```